# plist not giving the data the way entered

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

**Before I start, I am creating plist programmatically**

I am storing the path names of images in plist (programmatically). While saving I took NSLog and below is what I have

```
2013-08-04 15:25:24.044 XXX[12595:13d03] inserting data is 5===http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-08-04-07-42-37.25_tstdddd.png
2013-08-04 15:25:24.057 XXX[12595:13d03] inserting data is 4===http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-08-04-07-18-20.673_iphone_2.jpg
2013-08-04 15:25:24.086 XXX[12595:13d03] inserting data is 2===http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-07-21-03-14-29.292_Spare-Parts-summer-Ad-hyundai.jpg
2013-08-04 15:25:24.087 XXX[12595:13d03] inserting data is 1===http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-07-21-03-11-55.395_horizon.jpg
2013-08-04 15:25:24.089 XXX[12595:13d03] inserting data is 6===http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-08-04-08-03-29.371_2010.jpg
```

the data is entered with id 5,4,2,1,6.

Now when I read this data, below is what I am getting.

```
2013-08-04 15:27:28.251 XXX[12595:13d03] fetching URL == http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-08-04-07-18-20.673_iphone_2.jpg
2013-08-04 15:27:28.252 XXX[12595:13d03] fetching URL == http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-08-04-07-42-37.25_tstdddd.png
2013-08-04 15:27:28.252 XXX[12595:13d03] fetching URL == http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-07-21-03-11-55.395_horizon.jpg
2013-08-04 15:27:28.252 XXX[12595:13d03] fetching URL == http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-08-04-08-03-29.371_2010.jpg
2013-08-04 15:27:28.252 XXX[12595:13d03] fetching URL == http://www.mysite.com/faces/ProjectUploadFiles/hotDeals/mobile_2013-07-21-03-14-29.292_Spare-Parts-summer-Ad-hyundai.jpg
```

means while fetching I get data with 4,5,1,6,2

When I double click plist, I have data with id sorted i.e. I have data as 1,2,4,5,6.

Any idea why plist is providing random data?

Below is the screen shot of plist that is getting generated.

[image]

---

### Edit 1

For Storing data, below is the code I have.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Offers.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


    NSError *error;
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])
    {
        //TODO: Handle/Log error
        NSLog(@"files not deleted...");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"files deleted...");
    }

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Offers.plist"] ];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *data002 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        data002 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    }
    else
    {
        // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
        data002 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    int count;

    for (count = 0; count < (int)[news count]; count++)
    {
        [data002 setObject:[[news objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"imagePath"] forKey:[[news objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [data002 writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    }

    [data002 release];

}
```

---

### Answer

What I did is instead of NSMutableDictionary I used NSMutableArray and all worked perfectly.

Comment: Wrap the dictionaries in an array and write that into the plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You plist is a dictionary, it has no order, just keys and values. If you need to store the order then change to use an array (of dictionaries) or use an additional file to store the order.

---

`data002` is a dictionary. That's what makes your plist a dictionary (when you call `writeToFile:`). If you want to maintain the relative order you need to decide which approach you want to take and then create an `NSArray` of the items in order and use `writeToFile:` on the array to save it.

Comment: Your questions says you're doing it programatically so there is no default. Show the code. Save an `NSArray`.

Comment: I used NSArray while saving data and all is working fine... thanks for all support...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in order to maintain sequential data you would have to use an array of strings in the plist file rather than directly inserting strings to the root element (which is a dictionary). Alternatively, if you wish to store more complex entities, I would recommend indexing them and referring to the indexes alone in a separate array to maintain order.

[image]

Tap on the "+" sign to add an element, then select "Array" from the drop down menu under "type"

If you're doing this in code, simply insert an NSArray as an object in the NSDictionary you're saving as a plist:

```
[data002 setObject:@[path1,path2,path3] forKey:@"orderedArray"];
```

Comment: "I want to do everything programmatically... nothing using code." ??

Comment: @FahimParkar sorry, my answer can't get any clearer than what I've written down. I hope you're not expecting me to rewrite your code.

Comment: see my answer... just changed NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray and it worked...